# requestAction Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp-3

Boa tarde, gostaria de uma ajuda para fazer um requestAction no Cakephp 3, antes no cake2 eu fazia dessa forma:

```
<?php $post = $this->requestAction('/Posts/latest'); foreach ($post as $value) : ?>


function latest() 
{
    return $this->Post->find('all', array('order' => 'Post.id DESC','limit' => 1));
}
```

Comment: Relação: http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2014/09/15/view-cell-cakephp-3-quick-start/

Comment: Outra relacionada: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30348446/6402423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->requestAction(['controller' => '', 'action' => ''], ['pass'] => ['algum parametro se houver']);
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Poderia explicar como sua resposta resolve o problema, quanto mais detalhes an sua resposta melhor

Comment: Exatamente isso, muito obrigado